# Docker child image doesn't inherit packages installed in base image

Tags: docker

I need to have a hierarchy of the following Docker images:

A "base"image:

```
FROM python:3.5-slim-stretch
RUN apt install -y python3-enchant enchant libpq-dev gcc && apt clean
```

And a child image that inherits from the "base" likewise:

```
FROM myprivaterepo:30999/base-image
ENV PATH /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin:$PATH
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

The requirements.txt includes packages that are meant to be built with `gcc` and one of them needs to find the `pg_config` binary included in the `libpq-dev` package. The problem is that it cannot find them, even if it inherits and starts to build normally from the base image. (although if I install them in the child image, it all works - but that's not what I want.)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever built the base-image without that software? Then, it might be a caching problem of docker images, i.e. your child image is based on an old cached version of the base-image.

Verify that the following hashes match:

- Building your base image prints as last line:

`Successfully built <hash>`

- Building your child image prints in the beginning:

`Step 1/x : FROM myprivaterepo:30999/base-image
 ---> <hash>`

The `<hash>` should be identical.

Comment: You are rigtht. My child image didn't take the correct latest base image. Thanks.